# What's the best way to overfit a neural network?

Tags: javascript, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

I've been playing with this online demo of a in-browser https://cs.stanford.edu/people/karpathy/convnetjs/demo/image_regression.html and I've been trying to make the image with text (the one with "What does the fox say..." caption) to appear more clearer (with readable text) to no avail.

This neural network receives two inputs - X and Y positions of a pixel and three outputs - RGB channels for said pixel. The network is trained by a selected picture and then tries to "draw" it.

I would like to train this network in a way that would make each pixel match as close as possible to the original image, i.e. make it overfit. How can this be achieved? What combination or parameters should be used? Maybe the structure of the networks needs to be different (more layers, more neurons in layers, different type of layers, etc.)?

I've tried playing with the learning rate without changing the structure from the original, but even after 400k iterations most of the text is indistinguishable:

[image: screenshot after 400k iterations]

Is it just a matter of time and maybe after a few millions iterations the desired result will be achieved? Can it be sped up somehow (without increasing the processing power and other obvious stuff)?

It seems that making it return the same value for the same inputs every time should be a really easy task - the network in being trained on the exact same data hundreds of thousand of times, so why does it still return so many gray pixels?

I'm new to neural networks, so maybe it's a stupid question and neural networks can't be used for that at all.

Comment: Did you try semantic segmentation?

Comment: No. Can you please show me how it can be done with this specific JS library?

Comment: I don't know about this JS library but I've used semantic segmentation for images in Caffe.

Answer (score 5):

It will be quite hard to overfit such network, as effectively it is just regressor from 2D, so you need to model very "bumpy" surface. What you will need is lots of hidden units - this is essentialy what gives you capacity to overfit.

> Is it just a matter of time and maybe after a few millions iterations the desired result will be achieved?

No, network can actually have too small capacity to represent the problem.

> Can it be sped up somehow (without increasing the processing power and other obvious stuff)?

Yeah, do not use .js (kind of obvious too, but this is supposed to be web based example, not efficient technique).

> It seems that making it return the same value for the same inputs every time should be a really easy task - the network in being trained on the exact same data hundreds of thousand of times, so why does it still return so many gray pixels?

Why is it hard? Aren't NNs supposed to overfit easily? They overfit easily for **high dimensional problems**, where your data points are easy to separate using hyperplanes combinations (which are building blocks of neural nets). Here you are working with 2D, very low dimension, very dense data, which is away from typical NN method. If you want to make it learn an image easily you should treat an image as an input, whole image. Here, instead, each pixel is an input, which makes learning process relatively hard for NN.

Comment: Thanks for a detailed answer. So, there's no way to do it with this JS library and similar network setup (1 pixel as input)? You said that lots of hidden inputs can help, any ideas on the exact numbers?